No puedo visualizar los hilos en un chat con django 5.0
Estoy haciendo un chat con hilos(thread) con django 5.0, realice el chat  para guardar la conversación ya revise la Base la Datos para verificar si la conversación se guardo y si se a guardado la conversación pero no se logra visualizar la conversación en las plantillas(templates). Podrían ayudarme por favor
aqui les dejo el codigo de mi views.py
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import Http404
from .models import Thread

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


# Create your views here.
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class ThreadList(TemplateView):
    template_name = "messenger/thread_list.html"
    
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class ThreadDetail(DetailView):
    model = Thread  
    
    def get_object(self):
        obj = super(ThreadDetail, self).get_object()
        if self.request.user not in obj.users.all():
            raise Http404()
        return obj


codigo de la plantilla thread_list.html
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Mensajes{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<style>
  .avatar  { width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px; }
</style>
<main role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto mb-5">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Hilos de conversación -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Recorremos los Threads y sólo mostramos los que tienen como mínimo 1 mensaje -->
            {% for thread in request.user.threads.all %}
              {% if thread.messages.all|length > 0 %}
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <!-- Recorremos los miembros del hilo menos el propio request.user -->
                  {% for user in thread.users.all %}
                    {% if user != request.user %}   
                      <!-- Mostramos el avatar del miembro -->  
                      {% if user.profile.avatar %}
                        <img src="{{user.profile.avatar.url}}" class="avatar">
                      {% else %}
                        <img src="{% static 'registration/img/no-avatar.jpg' %}" class="avatar">
                      {% endif %}
                      <!-- Mostramos la información del miembro -->
                      <div>
                        <a href="{% url 'messenger:detail' thread.pk %}">{{user}}</a><br>
                        <small><i>Hace {{thread.messages.last.created|timesince}}</i></small>
                      </div>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <!-- Hilos de conversación -->
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <p><i>Selecciona un hilo de conversación de tu panel izquierdo.</i></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
{% endblock %} 

codigo del detalle de la plantilla thread_detail.html
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Hilo{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<style>
  .avatar  { width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:10px; }
  .thread  { max-height:300px; overflow-y:auto; padding:0 0.5em;} 
  .mine    { padding:0 0.5em 0.25em; background-color:rgba(230,242,245,.5); width:92%; margin-left:8%; }
  .other   { padding:0 0.5em 0.25em; background-color:#f2f3f5; width:92%; }
</style>
<main role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto mb-5">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Hilos de conversación -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Con una búsqueda inversa user.threads también podemos conseguir los hilos de un usuario -->
            {% for thread in request.user.threads.all %}
              <!-- Sólo mostraremos un Thread si tiene como mínimo 1 mensaje -->
              {% if thread.messages.all|length > 0 %}
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <!-- Recorremos los miembros del hilo menos el propio request.user -->
                  {% for user in thread.users.all %}
                    {% if user != request.user %}     
                      <!-- Mostramos el avatar del miembro -->                
                      {% if user.profile.avatar %}
                        <img src="{{user.profile.avatar.url}}" class="avatar">
                      {% else %}
                        <img src="{% static 'registration/img/no-avatar.jpg' %}" class="avatar">
                      {% endif %}
                      <!-- Mostramos la información del miembro --> 
                      <div>
                        <a href="{% url 'messenger:detail' thread.pk %}">{{user}}</a><br>
                        <small><i>Hace {{thread.messages.last.created|timesince}}</i></small>
                      </div>
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <!-- Hilo de conversación -->
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <!-- Recorremos los miembros del hilo menos el propio request.user -->
            {% for user in thread.users.all %}
              {% if user != request.user %}       
                <h4 class="mb-4">Mensajes con <a href="{% url 'profiles:detail' user %} ">{{user}}</a></h4>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <!-- Mostramos los mensajes en una capa que tiene un overflow vertical de 300 píxeles -->
            <div class="thread" id="thread">
              {% for message in object.messages.all %}
                <!-- Dependiendo del usuario asignamos una clase con un color de fondo u otro en el mensaje -->
                <div {% if request.user == message.user %}class="mine mb-3"{% else %}class="other mb-3"{% endif %}>
                  <small><i>Hace {{thread.messages.last.created|timesince}}</i></small><br>
                  {{message.content}}
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <!-- Aquí crearemos el formulario -->
            <button id="testBtn">Petición asíncrona de prueba</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
{% endblock %} 



No puedo visualizar la conversación del chat, espero su pronto ayuda
